# need to submit commit to a branch

Tags: git, gerrit

I am co-working with other people. ( other company )

They use gerrit to review commit.

The problem (rule) is, I can't push my commit to master directly, I need to push to a branch first, then they will review and merge it.

so:

1. The remote site (Admin) needs to create a branch for me? I can't create a local branch then push to remote.
2. When Admin created a branch (ex: tea_branch) for me, that branch is only to submit a patch, maybe 10 days later, the master branch already has many new commits, will it auto merged to tea_branch? or I need to request Admin to do this?
3. Can I still work on the master branch locally but push to tea_branch when needed? or whenever I want to submit a commit, I need to work at tea_branch, that is my concern, the tea_branch may not keep up-to-date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push to a new branch directly. In fact, the act of pushing creates this new branch. E.g.:

```
$ git push ssh://sshusername@hostname:29418/projectname HEAD:refs/for/mybranch
```

If `master` advanced while your branch was under review, the act of merging it should automatically rebase your change and then merge it. If there are merge conflicts, the merge will fail, and the reviewer should ask you to rebase yourself to solve the conflicts.

Comment: 29418 is a fixed constant everyone should use?

Comment: ex: git push ssh://green.tea@abcd.com:29418/project HEAD:refs/for/mybranch ?

Comment: @GreenTea That's the port gerrit usually uses. I don't know if it can be configured to use a different port

Answer (score 1):

I would not work on master locally.

I'd checkout tea_branch locally and do my changes on that.

If you're properly hooked up to the remote - e.g. by doing `git clone` then checking out a branch that exists remotely creates a local branch with that's set up to the branch the admin made for you.

You should merge code changes from master regularly.  More often means that the changes are smaller and less likely to cause conflicts.  But also you get a bit of distraction in your workflow, so find a pattern that suits.

You should definitely merge from master into yo
ur branch before creating your merge request.  That way you can resolve any merge conflicts before they happen, and adjust for any changes that have occurred in master that affect your code.
I do that by

`git fetch`

`git merge origin/master`

Comment: If I merged master manually to tea_branch, it seems I need to push these merged commits to remote tea_branch first before push my patch to remote tea_branch